# C# Substring() stops string at & symbol

Tags: c#, string, substring

C# Substring() doesn't work, it stops before & symbol:

```
var name = "my_company_&_friends";
var sub = name.Substring(2);
// sub should be all string starting with symbol index 2
// sub should be "_company_&_friends"
// but it is "_company_"
```

Is this a bug ? how to fix it ?

Comment: How are you displaying `sub`? I just ran that code in a console application along with a `Console.WriteLine()` and the result looks fine.

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're rendering that to HTML and forgetting to escape.

Comment: Nope, Can't reproduce it.

Comment: C# is not the problem

Comment: My psychic debugging skills agree with those of `SLaks`, since the code given works perfectly, but outputting it as HTML would indeed show `_company_`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code... See here https://dotnetfiddle.net/EWwMmG

Comment: Yeah, that was it, my filename had &, and it was passed by html, so it was cut by symbol &.

Answer (score 0):

it is what you are expecting
http://csharppad.com/gist/f38e23c03c66664698a7

What you are doing after this could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

problem on your end.
On mysystem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cWNZ.png